# Promises.all ficam em loop infinito

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, assincronismo, promises

Tenho o seguinte segmento de codigo:

```
        generateEpisode(result,programId).then((arrayBlocks) =>{

            const promises = []

            arrayBlocks.map((file,index) =>{
                promises.push(normalizeFile(file,index))
            });

            Promise.all(promises).then((finalFiles) =>{
                res.render("user/episodes/reviewEpisode",{script: finalFiles});
            }).catch((error) =>{
                req.flash("error_msg", error.message);
                res.redirect('/user/episodios');
            });

        }).catch((error) =>{
            req.flash("error_msg", error.message);
            res.redirect('/user/episodios');
        });
```

No qual a função `normalizeFiles()` cria um novo arquivo para cada arquivo que conter no `arrayBlocks`, porém as promises estão corretas, mas depois de resolvê-las e gerar os arquivos, elas começam a resolver novamente mesmo já as tendo resolvido, virando um loop infinito e nunca renderizando a view.

função `normalizeFiles`:

```
async function normalizeFile (file,index){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{

        let newFilename = "newFIle"+(index+1)+'-'+Date.now()+".wav";

        normalize({
            input: './public/uploads/'+file,
            output: './public/uploads/result/'+newFilename,
            loudness: {
                normalization: 'ebuR128',
                target:
                {
                    input_i: -23,
                    input_lra: 7.0,
                    input_tp: -2.0
                }
            },
        }).then(() =>{
            console.log('created the file!');
            resolve(newFilename);
        }).catch((error) =>{
            console.log('error!')
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Podes mostrar a função `normalizeFile`?

Comment: Editei o post e adicionei a normalizeFile

Comment: Adiciona `return` antes de `Promise.all` dentro de `generateEpisode(...).then(`

Comment: Podes simplificar escrevendo somente `const promises = arrayBlocks.map(normalizeFile); return Promise.all(promises);`

Comment: Ainda sim ele continua em loop, exemplo, coloquei pra imprimir os arquivos gerados e as promisses do map (nesse caso o arrayBlocks tinha 2 arquivos).resultado: `[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]` `[ 'newFile 1-1568378345251.wav', 'newFile 2-1568378345258.wav' ]` `[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]`

Comment: Mas sabes se ele vai para o `.catch(`? e qual deles?

Comment: Ele não para em nenhum catch, o `console.log(finalFiles)`, ta dentro do ultimo `.then(` dai ele imprime os dois arquivos gerados: `[ 'newFile 1-1568378345251.wav', 'newFile 2-1568378345258.wav' ]` e depois volta a imprimir as promises e gerar denovo e denovo, mas nunca renderiza a view e fica em loop gerando todos os arquivos

Answer (score 0):

Quando você faz o uso da notação `async` não é necessário retornar uma `Promisse` pois isso já acontece automaticamente.
Segue abaixo uma nova maneira de chegar no resultado esperado, altere seu método `normalizeFile` pelo conteúdo abaixo:

```
async function normalizeFile (file,index){
    let newFilename = "newFIle"+(index+1)+'-'+Date.now()+".wav";

    try {
        let result = await normalize({
            input: './public/uploads/'+file,
            output: './public/uploads/result/'+newFilename,
            loudness: {
                normalization: 'ebuR128',
                target:
                {
                    input_i: -23,
                    input_lra: 7.0,
                    input_tp: -2.0
                }
            },
        });

        console.log('created the file!');
        return result;        
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error!')
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Ou então você pode simplesmente remover o `async` declarado antes da function e manter o seu código com o retorno da Promise.

Você pode estar se aprofundando em Promises e vendo sobre async/await na [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas).

Obrigado.

Comment: construindo a `normalizeFiles` dessa forma, ele passar direto sem passar pela função e quando se pede para imprimir as promises os inves de imprimir `Promise { pending }` ele só imprime `undefined`

Comment: @tanji tem certeza que colocou o `await` antes do `normalizeFiles`?